# How to install a WordPress Website on Github

Tags: wordpress, git, github

Hy,

I have one question, how i can install a Wordpress Website on github and share with other contributors, and all persons works on the same project?

Regards

Comment: Research here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bwordpress%5d%20%5bgithub%5d%20is%3aquestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the changes you made is in wordpress store in database so, But for themes and code edit
 you can init it in one folder then install wordpress , push to git, 
If you already have wordpress file create repo and init on this wordpress folder,